# Complex derivative as a real derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis

Part (a) 
Suppose $f'(z)$ is a complex derivation of $f(z)$. Since $f'(z)$ takes complex values, $f'(z)$ is a $2 \times 1$ column vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Part (b)
If I interpret $f$ as function between $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then the derivation $f'(z)$ becomes a $2 \times 2$ linear tranformation.

Conclusion of Part (a) and Part (b) don't match up. Why?

Comment: What is the $2 \times 1$ vector given by $f'(z)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't match up"?

Comment: @TedShifrin: f'(x) is 2 x 1 matrix in part (a) and 2 x 2 matrix in part (b). How do you explain this inconsistency?

Comment: @Gibbs It depends on what f(z) is. but we know for sure f'(z) is a complex function, so it should be of the form 2 x 1 matirx

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh so if $f(z) = z^2$ what do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real derivative of a holomorphic function (which is required for the complex derivative to exist) at a point is the product of some multiple of the identity matrix with a rotation matrix (this is the reason for the name "holomorphic": it preserves angles, unless the derivative is $0$). Thus only a $2$-dimensional subspace of the $2\times2$ matrices appear. Specifically, only matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some real $a,b$ appear in this setting. Alternatively, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied iff the real derivative has exactly this form.

The corresponding complex derivative is $f'(z)=a+bi$, or $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$$in your matrix form.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought about it, and I concluded that I stand by what I said originally.

Comment: @Arthur: If I understood you correctly, you are saying 2x2 matrix is of rank 1 and hence can be reduced to 2x1 matrice. If that's true, then should both the map induce same linear transf.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh  The $2\times 2$ matrix above has determinant $a^2+b^2$, and is therefore either invertible or $0$, so $1$ is the only rank it _can't_ have. Also, they _do_ induce the same linear map. Remember that the $2\times1$ matrix is really a complex number, so you can multiply two of them together, and the result is the same as if you let the left one be the $2\times2$ matrix and use regular matrix multiplication. This way they are both points in the plane and linear maps of the plane at the same time.

Comment: @Arthur: So what's happening here is we are making use of the fact that $R^2$ is field in complex situation where in real-situation its only a vector space.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh That, and the fact that holomorphic functions are very limited so that the space of possible derivatives is two-dimensional. You could even say that making this work is how we define complex multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

They don't match up because they are different objects. This should be familiar: for functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R,$ $f'(x)$ is a number, while $Df(x)$ is the unique linear transformation from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x+h)-f(x) = Df(x)(h) + o(h).$ We do have $Df(x)(h) = f'(x)h$ for all $h,$ so the two objects have a direct connection, but they shouldn't be confused with each other, and therefore the same notation, $f'(x),$ shouldn't be used for both of them - at least not until the difference between the two is fully absorbed.

Moving to $\mathbb C= \mathbb R^2,$ things will again be confusing if the notation $f'(z)$ is used for two different objects, namely the complex derivative, which is the number $f'(z),$ and the corresponding (real) linear transformation $Df(z):\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2.$ It's the same "problem" as in the first paragraph. There's no actual problem unless we get careless with the notation.